# MVC Unable to display Linq query result to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to display linq results into a view but I have not been able to. The error I get is "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.Double,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable"

I created my view manually and by right clicking the controller and adding a view but I'm kind of stuck here.

```
public ActionResult leftjoin()
     {
        var q = from b in db.OrderHistories
                 join c in db.BuyerComms on b.ITEMID equals c.ITEMID into sr
                 from x in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new { Item = b.ITEMID, buyer = x.Buyer };
                 return View (q.ToList());


     }
```

and my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<myapp.Models.OrderHistory>
```

I used linqpad to test my linq and I'm getting the right results.

Comment: Well your results are a list of an Anonymous type.  An Anonymous type is not `myapp.Models.OrderHistory`.

Comment: you can't returning anonymous type from function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is returning an anonymous type as indicated by:

```
select new { Item = b.ITEMID, buyer = x.Buyer };
```

You need to instead select into a type of `OrderHistory`. You didn't provide that class, so I'm going to guess that it's something like:

```
select new OrderHistory { Item = b.ITEMID, buyer = x.Buyer };
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up creating a view on the database that does the join. I could not get the Linq. Thanks. I'll mark this as an accepted answer.